# Prototype error: Prototype.Browser is undefined in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, prototypejs

Meanwhile I am playing with Prototype and its progress bar 
http://www.learntechnology.net/content/ajax/ajax_upload.jsp

However, when I am using Firefox,
I get these few **errors** from Firebug:

```
Prototype.Browser is undefined 
   this.useARIA = page.util.useARIA() && !Prototype.Browser.IE;

e.href is undefined 
   if ( e && e.href.indexOf("#contextMenu") >= 0 )

e.href is undefined 
   if ( e && e.href.indexOf("#contextMenu") >= 0 )
```

Anyone could help me on this issue?

Comment: What version of Prototype are you using? What do you get in firebug when you type `Prototype`? Are there any other errors occurring sooner?